# Xubuntu + docker

Tags: xubuntu, docker

I recently installed Xubuntu Desktop with the intention of using it as a dev server as well.

Can Xubuntu run Docker/ Docker containers?

Comment: Why would Xubuntu be any different from Ubuntu and other variants regarding software support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly! That's one of the many benefits of running Linux on your desktop or laptop.

I would recommend installing Docker CE (Community Edition) from their official repository using their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Here's how to install it in short:

- Install some prerequisites:

  - `sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common`
- Add Docker's GPG key:

  - `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
- Add Docker's repository:

  - `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`
- Update and install:

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install docker-ce`